# Garage wall removal

Tags: walls, garage

Detached 25' x 25' garage with a wall running down the middle of it.
I would like to remove the wall to make better use of the space, but I'm unsure if the roof will collapse if I do so. Can it be removed? I have attached some photos in hopes it will help someone give me some advice. Apologies for the poor quality of the photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Typically, for a rough estimate, you could consider using a 12″×15″ RCC beam, 12-14″ GLULAM or LVL (laminated veneer lumber), W14 steel beam, a triple 2×16 wood beam, or ismb-350 for 2-3 storey residential building applications.

Comment: I have a very different take on this- Those appear to be pre-manufactured roof trusses that form the ceiling and the roof structure. In my experience any load bearing wall would have a vertical member built into the trusses right above the wall. You need to have an engineer (or a truss manufacturing company) look to confirm whether that is a bearing wall or not. Bottom line- it is worth the expense to truly know what your options are. No one here can give you anything but opinions about this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a Professional such as an Engineer,  is required to determine the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Almost nobody frames a wall and doesn't cover it unless they need it to support the structure.

That doesn't mean you can't get that opened up a lot. For a doorway or two it is just like putting an opening in an outside wall; frame to transfer the forces around it.

If you want a wider passage than that, you should get an expert, probably an engineer. to discuss what you need and design a solution,

And installing it may be a bit complicated since the building must always be supported and  the new beam has to pick up the weight and transfer it down to an adequate foundation. Quite doable. But you may want to hire pros for this too. They're insured against something unexpected going wrong. You aren't.